# Cannot Access remote CentOS machine using VNC

Tags: centos, remote-desktop, linux-networking, remote-access, vnc

I am trying to connect to a remote CentOs machine through VNC to get a graphical display.

I have followed the steps mentioned in https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-centos-6.5 to install and configure VNC server on my CentOS machine.

I have used the Iptable command to open 5901 port as well.

However on my ubuntu machine when I type vncviewer and type my the remote server's IP address I get the following error:

```
main:        unable to connect to host: No route to host (113)
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by specifying the port number along with the IP Address:

vncviewer 
IPAddress:5901